# SQL Query to Join Multiple Tables with Sum Function

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to combine 5 tables:

```
history - (contract_no, run_date, dataset_code)
premium - (contract_no, trx_amt)
contract - (contract_no, status, owner_idn)
confund - (contract_no, blg_method, blg_status)
client - (client_idn, client_ssn)
```

Ultimately, I want the results to show like this:

Contract No | Run_Date | DataSet_Code | Status | Blg_Method | Blg_Status | Suspense_Total

My biggest issue has been in getting the SUM function to work.  The trx_amt from the premium table is where I get my suspense total. A contract can have numerous rows.  Also, within that table the trx_amt can be from the contract_no or a client_ssn.

```
SELECT history_contract_no, 
       history_run_date, 
       history_dataset_code, 
       contract_status, 
       confund_blg_method,
       confund_blg_status,
       SUM(premium_trx_amt)  

FROM   HISTORY LEFT JOIN PREMIUM
ON     history_contract_no = premium_contract_no JOIN CONFUND 
ON     history_contract_no = confund_contract_no JOIN CONTRACT
ON     confund_contract_no = contract_contract_no  

WHERE  history_dataset_code in ('CONTINU1', 'CONTINU2')
AND    history_run_date between 20140118 and 20140124

GROUP BY history_contract_no
```

Without the SUM function above, I can get close, but I get multiple rows if a contract has more than one entry of suspense.  I cannot figure out how to sum those rows in my results.  I also cannot even get close in figuring out how to bring in the fifth table "client", so that I can sum up suspense entries that are sitting on the client_ssn and not under contract_no.  The contract_no in premium field is either an SSN or a contract_no.

I am fairly new to SQL (couple months), I am really wanting to do more complex queries, so if you know a good resource or tutorial, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: What is `history_field` that you have in two of your joins?

Comment: If you need to join with two different tables and combine the results, you should probably be using a UNION

Comment: I fixed the history_field (typo) and I had cut off my GROUP BY field.

Comment: Can you direct me on setting up a UNION or how to learn more about UNIONS?

Comment: `query1 UNION query2` simply performs the two queries and returns both result sets. It should be explained in any SQL tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the Sum function, you need to have a 'Group By' clause in your query.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT history_contract_no, 
       history_run_date, 
       history_dataset_code, 
       contract_status, 
       confund_blg_method,
       confund_blg_status,
       SUM(premium_trx_amt)  

FROM   HISTORY LEFT JOIN PREMIUM
ON     history_field = premium_contract_no JOIN CONFUND 
ON     history_field = confund_contract_no JOIN CONTRACT
ON     confund_contract_no = contract_contract_no

WHERE  history_dataset_code in ('CONTINU1', 'CONTINU2')
AND    history_run_date between 20140118 and 20140124

GROUP BY history_contract_no
, history_run_date
, history_dataset_code
, contract_status
, confund_blg_method
,confund_blg_status
```

If you would like to join on the client table as well, find which field in that table correlates between tables of interest.

Comment: This worked in regards to summing correctly!  I am working on a UNION tutorial to see if I cannot bring in the client table.  It looks like my error was not listing all the columbs in the GROUP BY part?

Comment: I know how the tables correlate, but I cannot figure out how to bring it together.  The CONTRACT table has the onwer_IDN which matches up to the CLIENT.client_IDN.  Then I can correlate the CLIENT.client_SSN to the contract_no on the PREMIUM table.

Comment: Seems like you need to follow the same strategy. Try adding another join as such `JOIN CLIENT
  ON contract_owner_id = client_client_idn` and in your select statement, add another sum field like `SUM(client_client_ssn)`. I hope I'm understanding this correctly.